# how to convert unix timestamp to mongodb date in php mongo query

Tags: php, mongodb

What will be the equivalent mongo php query. $time is filed of document having php unixtimestamp

`db.collection.aggregate({$project : { year : {$year : ISODate("$time"*1000)} }})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take this approach which adds the epoch date to the timestamp in milliseconds via the **[`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add)** operator (which would be as a result of another [**`$multiply`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#exp._S_multiply) operation on the time field by 1000 seconds) and the result will be the **[`$year`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/year/#exp._S_year)** part of your date milliseconds since epoch:

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    {
        "$project": {
            "year": {
                "$year": {
                    "$add": [ new Date(0), { "$multiply": [ "$time", 1000 ] } ]
                }
            }
         } 
    }
]);
```

The equivalent PHP syntax would be something like:

```
$collection->aggregate([
    [
        "$project" => [
            "year" => [
                "$year" => [
                    "$add": [ new MongoDate(0), [ "$multiply": [ "$time", 1000 ] ] ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far, are you using the php Mongo library?

Here an example with a timestamp:

```
$collection = $mongoClient->your_collection->your_type;
$pipeline = [
    [
        '$project' => [
            'year' => [
                '$year' => new \MongoDate($timestamp)
            ],
        ],
    ],
];

$results = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Comment: You cannot inject functions into aggregation pipelines. Only actual operators can be used. External values can be passed in, but external methods cannot act on pipeline values.

Comment: @Kiwi I tried the same but unfortunately Blakes is right we can't inject functions into aggregation pipelines. Also $timestamp is key of mongo document.